# Are precipitation and soil moisture time-independent variables?

Tags: copula, dependent-variable

I was studying about Copula functions from [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/copula). It says:

> Basically, copula is a set of mathematical tools that have the ability to connect two or more time-independent variables (Nelsen, $2003$)

As you can see, it says copula is used for "time-independent variables". But it is very strange to me, since I saw some papers used copula to model dependence structure between precipitation and soil moisture or flood peak and volume of flood.

I believe, for example both precipitation and soil moisture are time dependent variables since they vary over the time. I've also searched and [this site](https://training.weather.gov/pds/climate/pcu2/statistics/Stats/part1/CTS_TimeVar.htm) says,

> Climate Variables are time dependent variables: Each value has a time when this value took place. Simple way to look at climate time dependence is to plot the climate variable versus time.

So I'm really confused.

Comment: That characterization by Nelsen is a bit strange, and probably ependent on a specific context. See for instance  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X12000826  As for precipitation and soul moisture, maybe copulas is used for their dependence at a specific time point, even if both can be time series?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen This is **not** Nelsen's characterization!  Nelsen never considers or mentions time in his book.  It is a characterization by others who mention Nelsen in passing.  The problem here arises from relying on an abstract only and reading too much into it.

Comment: @whuber Yes, actually I couldn't find the citation in Nelsen's text too. One citation referred to  "An Introduction to Copula" book, which I couldn't find the text about time-independent variable. And another one referred this to "Nelsen, R. B. (2003), Properties and applications of copulas: A brief survey, in Proceedings of the First Brazilian Conference on Statistical
Modeling in Insurance and Finance, edited by J. Dhaene, N. Kolev, and P. A. Morettin, pp. 10–28, Univ. of Sao Paulo, Sao Paulo, Brazil." Which I couldn't find the paper.

Comment: So, ignore the phrase "time-independent" in the abstract.  It's meaningless, anyway: it's merely a hint that the authors of the abstract you are reading are interested in applying copulas (which are *not* about time series) to time series.